# how can I edit drop-downs using CSS?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to change the appearance of a drop-down box in an online form I've created, but I cannot figure it out at all. Does anybody have any styling tips/tricks with HTML/CSS that I can use to fix this?

Comment: can you change the html or only the css?

Comment: too broad - please google `CSS select box` or post more specific questions.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us what specifically you want to change, and what code you have written so far attempting to make that change.

Comment: Hi, @pherris, the first link that appeared when I googled CSS select box is actually the article that I am having issues understanding. [link](http://bavotasan.com/2011/style-select-box-using-only-css/) seemed to be on the right track but when I plugged it in I wasn't able to see the correct results.

Comment: <p class="form-field  Campaign_3__Do_you_post_schedules_and_schedule_rel pd-select     ">
    
     <label class="field-label" for="80622_29986pi_80622_29986">Do you post schedules and schedule related information on a bulletin board?</label>
    
    
    <select name="80622_29986pi_80622_29986" id="80622_29986pi_80622_29986" class="select" onchange=""><option value="" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="163368">Yes</option>
<option value="163370">No</option>
</select>
    
   </p>
   <div id="error_for_80622_29986pi_80622_29986" style="display:none"></div>

Comment: there's my code, sorry but I don't know how to format it correctly, this is my first time using stackoverflow. But I tried to add a div container around this and then copied and pasted the exact code from the link posted above and was unable to get a successful result.

Comment: as far as what I specifically want to change, currently the drop-down yes/no box is very plain, gray, and condensed. I would just like to understand my options on how I could tweak formatting, spacing, and text.

Answer (score 0):

for styling, try using border-radius: 5px; or use border: 2px solid #dcdcdc. maybe use the nth-child pseudo-class to target specific list items in the dropdown. good luck!